# Get all processes opened in a certain Desktop

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm working on an application that creates a new desktop when launched and using a key combo I can move back and forth between the original and the new desktop. At creation time, in the new desktop a new *explorer.exe* process is started, so the user can start whatever applications he desires.

When the key combo that sends the exit command is detected, the new desktop is closed, and we return to the original one, but all the applications that the user started in the new desktop are still running.

Is there a way to get a handle on all of this processes opened in the new desktop, having a `HANDLE` for the Window Station and a `HDESK` handle for the new Desktop?

Comment: A process can create windows in different desktops. What you are asking for, in general, is not well defined.

Comment: OOC Is this something for the new task view in windows 10 or do you mean separate desktops in any version of windows?

Comment: @JeffS I'm currently developing this application in Windows 7, so I would like to see if I can close every application started in the new desktop, under Windows 7

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was not aware that a process can create windows in different desktops. I am looking for a way to kill all processes opened by the user in that desktop alone, e.g. the users starts a notepad.exe process in the new desktop and when he prompts the key combo for exit, I would like to kill all those apps.

Comment: I think you first need to work out how you are going to categorise the processes that you want to kill. It's far from clear to me that you have a robust definition yet.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ... to start the new _explorer.exe_ I use `CreateProcess` function, that receives as one of the parameters a `STARTUPINFO` structure in which I set the desktop for the process. I thought that maybe there is a similar way to enumerate all processes and see in which desktop their windows resides, retrieve a handle, and close them.

Comment: You can probably call `GetThreadDesktop` on the main thread of each process that you enumerate, and that will likely be good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to David Heffernan's idea, I was able to find the following solution. Having a `HDESK` handle for the desktop, I compare it using `GetThreadDesktop` function with every thread from the system. I'm not sure that it's the most performant solution, I'm open towards suggestions for improvements, but this works just fine:

```c++
int main(void)
{
    // Desktop handles
    HDESK currentDesktop = GetsecondDesktop(GetCurrentThreadId());
    HDESK secondDesktop = CreateDesktop(L"secondDesktop", NULL, NULL, 0, GENERIC_ALL, NULL);

    // Start processes in secondDesktop ...

    // Process enumeration
    DWORD aProcesses[1024], cbNeeded, cProcesses;
    unsigned int i;
    EnumProcesses(aProcesses, sizeof(aProcesses), &cbNeeded);
    cProcesses = cbNeeded / sizeof(DWORD);

    for (i = 0; i < cProcesses; i++)
    {
        if (aProcesses[i] != 0)
        {
            DWORD pThreadId = ListProcessThreads(aProcesses[i]);
            if (GetsecondDesktop(pThreadId) == secondDesktop)
            {
                TerminateProcess(aProcesses[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

DWORD ListProcessThreads(DWORD dwOwnerPID)
{
    HANDLE hThreadSnap = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
    THREADENTRY32 te32;

    // Take a snapshot of all running threads  
    hThreadSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
    if (hThreadSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        return(FALSE);

    // Fill in the size of the structure before using it. 
    te32.dwSize = sizeof(THREADENTRY32);

    // Retrieve information about the first thread,
    // and exit if unsuccessful
    if (!Thread32First(hThreadSnap, &te32))
    {
        CloseHandle(hThreadSnap);     // Must clean up the snapshot object!
        return(FALSE);
    }

    // Now walk the thread list of the system,
    // and display information about each thread
    // associated with the specified process
    do
    {
        if (te32.th32OwnerProcessID == dwOwnerPID)
        {
            return te32.th32ThreadID;
        }
    } while (Thread32Next(hThreadSnap, &te32));

    //  Don't forget to clean up the snapshot object.
    CloseHandle(hThreadSnap);
    return 0;
}

BOOL TerminateProcess(DWORD dwProcessId)
{
    DWORD dwDesiredAccess = PROCESS_TERMINATE;
    BOOL  bInheritHandle = FALSE;
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(dwDesiredAccess, bInheritHandle, dwProcessId);
    if (hProcess == NULL)
        return FALSE;

    UINT uExitCode = 0;
    BOOL result = TerminateProcess(hProcess, uExitCode);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return result;
}
```